# Integrated Curvature on Manifolds in SageMath

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, curvature, sagemath

Is it possible to integrate the Ricci curvature scalar on an arbitrary $n$-dimensional manifold in SageMath? Just straight up:

$$\int R dV$$

Assume that I know how to get the Scalar curvature a la SageManifolds.

(In reality I'm just going to do this in 3D, if that matters...but I don't think it should.)